# Перебор всех возможных вариантов заполнения массива

Tags: c++, массивы, stl, комбинаторика, перебор

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать алгоритм?
Вводные данные:
Имеем массив на 100 элементов, типа bool.
как перебрать все варианты заполнения массива используя true 40 раз, остальное false?

Comment: Вы точно уверены, что хотите перебрать все варианты, число которых - 13746234145802811501267369720? Сколько времени вы его будете выводить? :)

Comment: Размерность можно изменить, интересует реализация)

Comment: @Harry, разве не 11215762526664624508781016841049139209146570250671219642011054243840000000000? UPDATE: Тьфу, я разделить забыл, все единицы ведь одинаковые. Сошлось: `res=1n;for(q=100n;q>60n;--q)res*=q;for(q=40n;q;--q)res/=q` - получается 13746234145802811501267369720.

Comment: @Qwertiy Это просто число сочетаний из 100 по 40 (или, что то же самое, 60) — 100!/(60!\*40!)...

Comment: @Harry, ага. Я сначала 100*99*...*61 посчитал. И только после написания коммента дошло, что надо ещё на 40! перестановок поделить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой вариант — создаем заранее упорядоченный массив данных и применяем стандартнейший [`next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation). [Вот](https://ideone.com/nDig0i) для количества 10-6-4:

```
string s = "0000111111";
do {
    cout << s << endl;
} while(next_permutation(s.begin(),s.end()));
```

Можете заменить на массив `bool`, если так уж нужно :)

Comment: Большущее вам спасибо!